# trigger sql null datetime variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, null

Iam writing an sql trigger with sql server
in this clause

```
IF  (@EXON = '' OR @DATEDEB='' OR @DATEFIN= '') AND @N_CATComp =4
```

`@DATEDEB` `@DATEFIN` are datetime variable and the application accept null values for those both variable I want in this case null is not accepted , this works only for the first variable `@EXON` 
plz help

Answer (score 0):

```
IF  (@EXON = '' OR ISNULL(@DATEDEB, '') ='' OR ISNULL(@DATEFIN, '') = '')
```

if it's null it'll return ''

Comment: thanks but the problem is not solved if DATEDEB null DATEFIN NULL AND EXON IS not null it works

Comment: @hollyx So what's the problem? You need to give more examples of the data and the expected output.

Comment: if @N_CATComp =4 the we must enter the three values which are EXON,DATEDEB,DATEFIN in my case if i enter only EXON value and N_CATCOMPT = 4 it pass but three values must be entered

Comment: @hollyx No idea what you mean, include in your answer the values and expected output.

Comment: if catcompt=4 then exon=123 and DATEDEB=10032016 and ,DATEFIN=11032016 if i have exon=123 and  DATEDEB='' and DATEFIN='' then this must be false error msg appears in my case if i enter only the EXON for catcomt=4 then there is no error but this is false   DATEDEB and DATEFIN must not be empty

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable @MyVar has it's value equal to null you should do this:

```
if (@MyVar IS NULL)
    print '@MyVar has a NULL value'
else
    print '@MyVar value is not NULL'
```

You should also check the documentation on the helper functions NULLIF and ISNULL.

Answer (score 0):

`IF  (@EXON = '' OR @DATEDEB='' OR @DATEDEB IS NULL OR @DATEFIN= '' OR @DATEFIN IS NULL) AND @N_CATComp =4`